# How can I pass a method as a function parameter?

Tags: methods, rust, parameters

I have a struct `A` with the implementation:

```
impl A {
    pub fn b(&self) {
        bar(/* ... */);
    }

    fn foo(&self) {
        // something
    }
}
```

Function `bar` receives another function as parameter. How can I pass the method `foo` as this parameter?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: `A::foo`

Comment: @Shepmaster but it is not bound with ```self```

Comment: That's correct, it takes `self` as an argument. The duplicate isn't long, and if you continue reading it, you'll see the solution: *if you want it with the `self` variable already bound [...] then you need to use an explicit closure*.